# Change active state based on which component is on screen

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What is the correct technique to do this?

For example,
If component A is in view, `.router-link-active` would point to the component A related `router-link`

But If i scroll further down the page, to Component B per say, `.router-link-active` would point to component B.

Comment: You can test which nodes are within the viewport using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

I have an example using it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52460697/2766908

You can update the code in that example to fit your use-case, which would be to update your router links in the IntersectionObserver callback when certain components come into view.